# Help needed on algebraic steps for Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Multivariate Normal Distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

The negative loglikelihood is as follows:

$$\dfrac{nd}{2} \log 2\pi + \dfrac{n}{2} \log |\Sigma| + \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \tag{1}$$

If I take differentiation with respect to $\mu$ on $(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)$, the result becomes as follows:
$$2\Sigma^{-1}\mu - 2\Sigma^{-1} = 2\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-x_i) \tag{2}$$

So

$$\dfrac{\partial l(u, \Sigma)}{\partial \mu} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n2\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-x_i) = \Sigma^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mu-x_i) \tag{3}$$

But what I can't do with the algebraic steps for the next step to get the following result:

$$\mu_{MLE}^{*} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \tag{4}$$

How can I go from $(3)$  to $(4)$? Hope to get algebraic steps for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy. Just equate the equation 3 to zero and solve for mu. Have a try and lets see what you get.

Have a look at this 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation

Example part. I think you get some mistake in your equations.

Comment: I have missed some part in the equation. 3. I have included $\sum_{i=1}^n$. I am horrible at doing algebraic steps...

Comment: Hope it is ok.
$$\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (\mu-x_i) = 0$$
$$n\mu-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$$
$$n\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
$$\mu = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$
$$\therefore \mu_{MLE}^{*} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

Comment: The last equation is correct and once you equate it to zero you will gt the answer, but I need to check all you equation to make sure they are correct.

Comment: You have some typo in third step. You miss x_i

Comment: Thank you for having me think about the problem. Even though I don't get the straight answer, I still get the support and it feels a lot better than being alone facing the wall. Thank you for taking your time, too.

Comment: Have a look at this https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/191.  For algebra and math in general I recommend you with these steps: 1- read the lesson and summary it as a points. Then to answer you question try to follow the points one by one. Then you will find yourself answer the question.